# Conditional Keyword Arguments (Ruby 2.0)

Tags: ruby

let's say I have this object:

```
class Post
  def initialize(title: 'title', content: 'content')
    @title = title
    @content = content
  end
end
```

but I would like to add logic like:

```
class Post
  def initialize(title: 'title', content: 'content')
    @title = title unless title.empty? # if it's empty I'd like to use the default value
    @content = content unless content.empty?
  end
end
```

In the above example, how do I assign a keyword argument conditionally?

Comment: The essense of your question is whether a method (not just `initialize`) can obtain the default values of parameters it is passed. You can obtain the calling method with [Kernel#caller](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) and some information about the arguments with [Method@#parameters](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Method.html#method-i-parameters).  Considering that default values may be computed and that Ruby has no reason to make them available to the called method, I doubt very much that there is way to get them from the called method. However,..

Comment: ...you might have a look at the `get_args` method of the [merb gem](http://rubydoc.info/github/merb/merb/master/GetArgs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel a code smell here. You are trying to assign the default value to the variables under two separated conditions: when the argument is not given, and when the argument is empty. That is not a good design. It is a potential cause of bugs, and makes maintenance difficult. I suggest you should take one of the two ways:

(i) Make the arguments obilgatory (i.e., pass `nil` or an empty value rather than not passing an argument), and do the validation in the method body:

```
class Post
  def initialize(title, content)
    @title = title.nil? || title.empty? ? "title" : title
    @content = content.nil? || content.empty? ? "content" : content
  end
end
```

(ii) Rather than passing an empty value as an argument, do not pass it:

```
class Post
  def initialize(title: "title", content: "content")
    @title, @content = title, content
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Revisiting this with a better answer...this is exactly what `fetch` is used for:

```rb
class Post
  def initialize(options)
    @title = options.fetch(:title, 'title')
    @content = options.fetch(:content, 'content')
  end
end
```

Here's how one would use this logic:

```
irb(main):007:0> post = Post.new(title: 'A Very Short Story', content: 'Hello World!')
=> #<Post:0x00007fadc6829878 @title="A Very Short Story", @content="Hello World!">
irb(main):008:0> post = Post.new(title: 'A Nonexistent Story')
=> #<Post:0x00007fadc6820138 @title="A Nonexistent Story", @content="content">  # Notice how 'content' was set using the default option
```

---

**Old (Valid But Uses More Code) Answer**

Why not set defaults in a separate method and then merge in the arguments passed at initialization? If arguments aren't passed, then the defaults kick in. Otherwise, the defaults are overwritten by the arguments passed in at initialization.

For example:

```rb
class Post
  def initialize(options)
    options = defaults.merge(options)
    @title   = options[:title]
    @content = options[:content]
  end

## Code omitted ##

  private def defaults
    {
      title:  "Your Default Title"
      content: "Your Default Content"
    }
  end
    ...
end
```